# Is it possible to change the volume per user in Webex?

Tags: webex

During many Webex meetings there is often a disparity of volume between various users making it so that I need to continually adjust the volume.

Is there a Webex feature or Windows workaround that would allow me to control the volume output of each user, or a way to normalize the volume of all users?

Answer (score 0):

Users can adjust the mic volume, e.g. in Windows settings outside of Webex. I don’t know of any way for the host or moderator to adjust users‘ volume inside Webex.